# How do I unit test Django views on the Google App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am struggling to run unit tests using the Django *Client* class on the Google App Engine. I downloaded GAEUnit (v2.0a for Django) and I am trying to use that as my testing framework (maybe I should rather be using something else?)

I copy all the GAEUnit files into my project root as instructed, and I modify my app.yaml file. Currently app.yaml looks as follows:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: django_bootstrap.py

- url: /test.*
  script: gaeunit.py
```

I also modified settings.py to add gaeunit as an application... (snippet from settings.py)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'gaeunit',
)
```

My unit test class resides in the 'test' folder and looks as follows (very simple):

```
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def testName(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'Test.testName']
    unittest.main()
```

However, when I try to run my application by navigating to http://localhost:8080, it fails with the following error:

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /
Could not import gaeunit.gaeunit. Error was: No module named gaeunit
```

gaeunit.py does definitely exist in the folder. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what was wrong here. I made two mistakes:

1. In *app.yaml*, url: /test.* had to be **before** url:/.*   (otherwise the /test URL would be matched to /.* before getting to the /test.* handler)
2. **Beware** of copying all the files from the GAEUnit package into your project root! The GAEUnit folder contains a urls.py file that will overwrite your one if you are not paying attention. This was happening in my case. I simply restored my original urls.py.
3. When working with the django test *Client*, and if you intend to access the response.template or response.context properties, you need to ensure that you call *django.test.utils.setup_test_environment()*, otherwise template and context will be *Nothing*. I call this in my test module, right at the bottom.

Result: working unit tests!

Comment: You can copy url but in your urls.py include     (r'^test', include('gaeunit.urls')),     Also you will have to change test path in gaeunit.py _LOCAL_DJANGO_TEST_DIR = 'test'